# What is the projective bundle over $(\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1)/(\Bbb Z/2)$ which isn't $\Bbb P(\mathcal{E})$ for some vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

I'm thinking about when a (Zariski-locally trivial) $\Bbb P^n$-bundle comes from the projectivization of a vector bundle, and I've found Sasha's answer [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306852/mathbbp1-bundle-over-compact-base/306885#306885) stating that $(\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1)/(\Bbb Z/2)$ has a $\Bbb P^1$-bundle which isn't the projectivization of a vector bundle. Unfortunately, it doesn't say what this bundle *is*. Does anyone know an explicit description of what the intended bundle is, and an easy way to see it's not the projectivization of a vector bundle?

Comment: The variety $B= (\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1)/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is the *base* of the bundle, not the total space.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yikes, thank you for the correction.

Comment: @HankScorpio Have you read the paper that Sasha refers to in the comments of his answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X = (\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1)/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$. This is a toric surface with 4 ordinary double points. Let
$$
\pi \colon Y \to X
$$
be the blowup of one of these points and let $E \subset Y$ be the exceptional curve. Then $E^2 = -2$ and one has
$$
Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_Y, \mathcal{O}_Y(E)) = 
H^1(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y(E)) \cong 
H^1(Y, \mathcal{O}_E(E)) \cong \Bbbk.
$$
Let the vector bundle $F$ on $Y$ be defined as the non-trivial extension
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_Y(E) \to F \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0.
$$
Then it follows from the construction that
$$
F\vert_E \cong \mathcal{O}_E(-1)^{\oplus 2}.
$$
Consider the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}_Y(F)$, the surface $S = \mathbb{P}_E(F\vert_E) \subset \mathbb{P}_Y(F)$, and the composition
$$
\mathbb{P}_Y(F) \to Y \to X.
$$
One can check that this composition has another factorization
$$
\mathbb{P}_Y(F) \to Z \to X,
$$
where the first morphism contracts the surface $S$ and the second morphism is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle, which is not isomorphic to the projectivization of a vector bundle.

For the proof see https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10628, Section 4.3.

**EDIT.** Here is an explanation why $Z \to X$ is not a projectivization.

Let $x_0 = \pi(E)$ and let $C \subset Z$ be the fiber of $Z \to X$ over $x_0$. If $Z \to X$ is a projectivization, there is a line bundle $L$ on $Z$ such that $L\vert_C \cong \mathcal{O}(1)$. Then the pullback of $L$ to $\mathbb{P}_Y(F)$ restricts to $S \cong E \times \mathbb{P}^1$ as $\mathcal{O}(0,1)$. On the other hand, the Grothendieck bundle of $\mathbb{P}_Y(F)$ restricts to $S$ as $\mathcal{O}(1,1)$. From this we conclude that there is a line bundle on $Y$ that restricts to $E$ as $\mathcal{O}(1)$, but this is impossible, because $Pic(Y)$ is generated by $\pi^*Pic(X)$ (which restricts to $E$ trivially) and by $\mathcal{O}_Y(E)$ (which restrict to $E$ as $\mathcal{O}(-2)$).

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, I don't really understand much of what's going on (maybe this is on me, I am still in my first course in AG). In particular, the linked section of the paper seems to treat computing some Brauer class map which I can't quite connect with the claims you make (how does this show that $Z\to X$ is not a projectivization, for instance?).

Comment: @HankScorpio: I added a sketch of the proof to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful - I think fleshing it out will be a good exercise for me.